# How to connect Ansible to AWS-EC2 via ssh

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to connect ansible to EC2 via ssh. I created a key pair on my local machine(ubuntu) and copied it to my EC2 instances using ssh-copy-id. The copy was successful, but I get the error below when I want to connect to my instance:

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@34.xxx.0x.xxx: Permission denied (publickey)
```

when I inspected the auth.log file on my remote machine I see the following logs:

```
invalid user usuario from 187.xx.xx.xx port 47988
```

Here is my etc/ansible/hosts file

```
[host1]

github ansible_host=13.xxx.xxx.xx ansible_user=root
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we should use domain credentials not the key based authentication to run playbook from control node to any of you remote server.

But in your case you are trying to authenticate using root user and the key. 
So follow the below steps:

- Create an user named as ansible & Create key at control node (
  ansible master server) for   user “ansible”.
- If you created keys for
  this user will get two files  private-key & public-key.
- Copy the
  public key content into of remote servers
  `“/home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys”`  which you want to manage via
  ansible control node.
- Now check the SSH using below command

  `ssh -i /path/to/private-key  ansible@<remoteserverip>`

  Hope this helps.

Regarding ansible configuration there will one parameter in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` about mentioning private. 
    `private_key_file = /path/to/private-key`

Comment: please, I tried it but I get the same error. This round, the public key is not even copied when I use ssh-copy-id.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set **PasswordAuthentication yes** in sshd_config file on the remote server and that resolved the problem